# Do I need a foreign key declaration in the individual table when creating join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, model-associations

I have a join table of "contents" and "roles" called content_roles and this is the join table.

```
class CreateContentRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :content_roles, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :content, foreign_key: "content_id"
      t.belongs_to :roles, foreign_key: "role_id"
    end
    add_index :content_roles, ["content_id", "roles_id"]
  end
end
```

So in the individual roles and contents migration, do I need to have a foreign_key that refers back to the join table and/or the roles/contents? Sorry, I didn't explain this any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` columns in the `content` and `roles` tables act as foreign keys. Rails joins the `content` and `content_roles` tables using `id` in `content` table and `content_id` in `content_roles` table. So are the `roles` and `content_roles` tables.

Answer (score 1):

why cant you use references as shown below

```
class CreateContentRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :content_roles, :id => false do |t|
    t.references :content, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.references :roles, index: true, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Hemanth. That looks very compact. I can use that. I am learning ruby on rails and I saw this video https://youtu.be/bkMbjMQBuZc @2:00 and the video showed it that way.